# Structs interface

Tags: c, struct

When you define a new `struct` is better to define also an interface to that type
(i.e. "setter" and "getter" functions) or to access members directly via `.` and `->` operators?

**EDIT**
Plain C programming

Comment: is it plain C or C++ is also?

Answer (score 12):

It depends on whether your struct is an abstract data type or not. If you make the struct definition public in your header, then defining accessors doesn't make any sense - API clients can still read/write fields directly, and, in C, they do have reasonable expectation that it will work.

On the other hand, you may want to hide the struct entirely, and only show its declaration to the clients, as a kind of an opaque handle:

foo.h:

```
typedef struct foo foo;

foo* foo_create();
void foo_free(foo*);
int foo_get_bar(foo*);
void foo_set_bar(foo*, int);
```

foo.cpp:

```
struct foo { 
  int bar;
};

foo* foo_create() { return malloc(sizeof(foo)); }

void foo_free(foo* p) { free(p); }

int foo_get_bar(foo* p) { return p->bar; }

void foo_set_bar(foo* p, int newval) { p->bar = nwval; }
```

client.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

foo* f = foo_create();
f->bar = 123; // compile error, bar is not defined
foo_set_bar(f, 123); // ok
```

The reason for doing it that way is 1) encapsulation, same as in OO, and 2) versioning - you may add new fields to your struct, or reorganize them freely, and old code will remain binary-compatible.

Comment: Either I'm doing something wrong (which is very likely), or this doesn't work with gcc. Does this work in C++ only? I'm confused by the .cpp extension among mentions to C-only.

Comment: Sorry, I got it. FTR, it works in plain C: f **can only be a pointer** (foo*, not foo), if only the declaration (not the definition) of the type is reachable.

Answer (score 3):

With C you would typically not define setters and getters for each struct member.

The advantages of setters and getters is present in C++ because you can do data hiding via private and protected.   With C there is no such concept of private and protected struct members.

Comment: You can hide the implementation of a struct through forward declaration. Getter/setter methods can then be used to access the members of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

If you were reading someone else's code, would you rather see:

```
setSomeValue(&aStruct, VALUE);
```

or:

```
aStruct.someValue = VALUE;
```

The syntax of the second makes it obvious that a field of aStruct is being set.  In the first, you're depending on the function and variable names chosen by the programmer to get that information.

Comment: No reason you couldn't write "aStruct.setSomeValue(VALUE)", assuming a proper init function to set some function pointers.

Comment: @Randy: how does the `setSomeValue` function know where the the struct is in memory?  A static pointer set up by the init routine?

Comment: Good question! I got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In C, if you are creating a new struct it already has setter/getter built in. If you are using a variable name, you use varName.memberElement and if you are using a struct pointer: pointer-->memberElement. For instance:

```
struct Random
{ 
   int temp; 
};
```

If we create a struct variable, `struct Random example` then we can access and set variables using the . notation.

```
example.temp = 12345;
```

If we create a struct pointer, we would use -> notation.

```
struct Random element, *pointer; 
pointer = &element;
```

We set pointer to point at element and then to access members,

```
pointer->temp = 12345;
```

No need to create separate setter/getter interfaces and functions in C. Don't make more work for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the size of the program and intended use.  Bear in mind that all members of a struct are public by default.  If you need them to be private, use "class" instead.

Comment: You are not observing that this is a C question and have given a C++ answer.

Comment: @Jonathan: At the time I replied, the clarification about using C was not yet present.

Answer (score -1):

Following up Brian Bondy's answer, in C you *cannot* have getters and setters; member functions are just not part of the language.

In C++, typically they are not used because structs almost always contain, by convention, Plain Old Data and the members are just accessed directly.